# one-to-many matching in bipartite graphs?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching, string-matching

Consider having two sets $L$ (left) and $R$ (right).
$R$ nodes have a capacity limit.
Each edge $e$ has a cost $w(e)$.

I want to map each of the $L$ vertices to one node from $R$  (one-to-many matching), with minimum total edge-costs.

Each vertex in $L$ must be mapped to one vertex in $R$ (but each node in $R$ can be assigned to multiple $L$-nodes).

Examples: Consider the capacity of $R$ nodes is $2$.

1) This is NOT correct, since one node from $L$ has not assigned to a node in $R$.

[image]

2) This is NOT correct, since the capacity of a node in $R$ is violated.

[image]

3) This IS correct. All $L$ nodes are assigned to a node in $R$, and the capacity of $R$ nodes is not violated.

[image]

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is called the B-matching problem. Where you are given a function $b:V \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ that assign a capacity to each vertex and a function $u:E \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ that assigns a weight to each edge.

The problem is solvable in polynomial time. An easy solution is to reduce the problem to minimum weight maximum matching. Create $b(v)$ copies of each vertex  $v$ and connect each of them to all neighbors of the original vertex v. We get a polynomial time reduction, since for $b(v) \geq \mathrm{deg}(v)$ we can set $b(v) := \mathrm{deg}(v)$ since we can not match $v$ with more vertices than its neighborhood anyway and that each of its neighbors is matched with at most one vertex in your special case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can $b$ be a function of edge weights?

Comment: I don't exactly get your question. Can you explain it more?

Comment: First, I would like to have different $b$ per vertex. 
Second, consider this example: if $b(v)=5$, I can match $(i,v)=2, (j,v)=3$. I can also match $(p,v)=2, (q,v)=2, (r,v)=1$. What happens in this case?

I also have a condition that all the $L$ nodes must be matched with something. How it can be handled in $b$-matching?

Comment: I mean $v \in L, \forall v$ must be matched and maximum with one node from $R$.

Comment: $b$ is a function so it is different for each vertex. Since $b(v) = 1$ for $v \in L$, it won't occur that one edge is used more than once. Hence, if a matching exists that saturates or the vertices on the left an algorithm for b-matching will always finds such a matching.

Comment: Thanks. Any other algorithms other than copying vertices?

Comment: Yes, the problem can also be reduced to finding minimum $T$-cut which is solvable in $O(n^4)$. See Combinatorial Optimization book by Korte or by Schrijver for more details.

Comment: The problem has also min-max characterization, which means you can solve it in polynomial time as a linear program using the ellipsoid method. However, I don't think you should consider this case for a real-life implementation. (Refer to the same books)